# ORA-00922 performing ALTER USER using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, sql, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

I'm trying to run an ALTER USER statement using the python module cx_Oracle, but I'm receiving the error "**cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option**"

```
        dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host_name, port, service_name=service_name)
        con = cx_Oracle.connect(user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASSWD, dsn=dsn)

        cursor = con.cursor()
        generated_passwd = random_passwd()

        sql = "ALTER USER " + user_to_reset + " IDENTIFIED BY \"" + generated_passwd + "\";"
        print(sql)
        cursor.execute(sql)
```

here is a sample query generated by my code that throws the ORA-00922 error when ran through cx_oracle:

```
ALTER USER john IDENTIFIED BY "vJe3lfRI9zma";
```

this query works in sqlplus so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. any help would be appreciated

Comment: get rid of the extra quotes for password

Comment: @OldProgrammer sadly that did not work. receiving the same error

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The semicolon at the end of my PL/SQL statement is the culprit of the error.

```
ALTER USER john IDENTIFIED BY "vJe3lfRI9zma"
```

works just fine in cx_Oracle.

Comment: In your case the issue was the semicolon but because you were running a SQL statement. If you run a PLSQL program , like calling a procedure or package, you will need the semicolon. The method execute will fail if it includes the sql terminator, semicolon for SQL or slash for PLSQL programs.